# Google Cloud storage - migrating to new version, getting 'maxResults' objects per prefix

Tags: php, api, google-cloud-storage

So we are migrating from an old version of the GCS PHP library (const LIBVER = "1.0.5-beta") to the newer version ( v1.22? v0.122.0? ). THe old way uses a GoogleClient object, and a derived Google_Service_Storage object, and lists the objects in a bucket that have a specified prefix:

```
self::$client = new Google_Client();
self::$service = new Google_Service_Storage(self::$client);

$page_token = null;
$prefix = 'AR0001/file_manager/Images/';
$objects = self::$service->objects->listObjects(<bucket name>,
                                                [ 'prefix' => $prefix,
                                                  'maxResults' =>10,
                                                  'pageToken' => $page_token
                                                ]);
printf("GOT %d objects\n", count($objects['items']) );
```

While the newer API has a direct call on the bucket to retrieve the objects:

```
self::$client = new StorageClient( [
                                     'projectId' => <my project id>,
                                     'keyFile'  => <key file stuff>
                                   ]
                                 );

$bucket = self::$client->bucket( <bucket name> );

$page_token = null;
$prefix = 'AR0001/file_manager/Images/';
$objects = $my_bucket->objects( [ 'prefix'     => $prefix,
                                  'maxResults' => 10,
                                  'pageToken'  => $page_token
                                ] );
printf("GOT %d objects\n", count($objects) );
```

I found the original issue, but that leads to the next - 'maxResults' doesn't seem to be working. I have set the "maxResults" in the params to be 10. In the "old" case, I get 10 results per call, and the page_token lets me get all the objects as I go. But in the new case, maxResults doesn't seem to work - I get all 66 objects in a single go. I set it to 10 to test my paging, but not sure why it doesn't work for the bucket->objects() case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According with the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-php) this is the recommended solution for list objects using a prefix:

```
function list_objects_with_prefix($bucketName, $prefix)
{
    $storage = new StorageClient();
    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
    $options = ['prefix' => $prefix,'resultLimit'=>2];
    foreach ($bucket->objects($options) as $object) {
        printf('Object: %s' . PHP_EOL, $object->name());
    }
}
```

There is an option at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) for test your prefix.

The client library will automatically paginate your requests as you iterate. So as you mention, a bucket of 12,000 objects will, without a custom maxResults setting, result in 12 API calls if you iterate over the entire set.

If you need to list several objects inside your bucked the client library will automatically paginate your request as you will iterate. For example if you have 4000 objects on your storage and you didn't set the maxResults, you will need to do 4 API calls for iterate over the entireset since is pointed at the official documentation that the default of maxResults is 1000

You can use the maxResult and resultLimit settings for retrieve a paged list of objects from the bucket.

For example:

```
use Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler;
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;

$handler = new CurlHandler();
$stack = HandlerStack::create($handler);
$stack->push(function (callable $handler) {
    return function (RequestInterface $request, array $options) use ($handler) {
        // only write the log for calls to list objects.
        $uri = $request->getUri()->getPath();
        if (substr_compare($uri, '/o', -2) === 0) {
            echo "Requesting page" . PHP_EOL;
        }
        return $handler($request, $options);
    };
});
$client = new Client(['handler' => $stack]);

$storage = new StorageClient([
    'httpHandler' => new Guzzle6HttpHandler($client)
]);

$bucket = $storage->bucket('my-bucket');

$i = 0;
foreach ($bucket->objects(['maxResults' => 1, 'resultLimit' => 5]) as $obj) {
    $i++;
    echo $i . ': ' . $obj->name() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The output will be something like this:

```
Requesting page
1: object-a
Requesting page
2: object-b
Requesting page
3: object-c
Requesting page
4: object-d
Requesting page
5: object-e
```

If you want to know about the options for this library, take a look at this [document](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.122.0/storage/storageclient?method=buckets).

Comment: Thanks, that part is working. Now I want to figure out why the maxResults parameter doesn't limit what comes back.

Comment: Thanks Harif. But I want to page my results - so the "maxResults" parameter should do that (on the page you sent, it is the "Maximum number of results to return per requested page.") As for the other page, an HTTP request/response is only useful if the PHP API matches it - I can't see writing my php code to switch back and forth between making PHP calls and CURL calls. My problem is that the PHP API call to bucket->objects() doesn't seem to work the way the documentation says that it does.

Comment: @AndyWallace I edit my answer, I hope will be useful for you